# CoreBluetooth state preservation: correct way to restore CBCentralManager

Tags: ios, cbcentralmanager, ble-state-preservation

what is the correct way to restore the CBCentralManager from AppDelegate when the App gets lunched with options due to a state preservation event?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // The system provides the restoration identifiers only for central managers that had active or pending peripheral connections or were scanning for peripherals.
    NSArray * centralManagerIdentifiers = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey];

    if (centralManagerIdentifiers != nil) {
        for (int i=0; i<[centralManagerIdentifiers count]; i++) {
            NSString * identifier = [centralManagerIdentifiers objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"bluetooth central key identifier %@", identifier);
            // here I expect to re-instatiate the CBCentralManager but not sure how and if this is the best place..
        }
    }

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you get list of identifiers, you have to iterate thru this list and initialise instance(s) of `CBCentralManager` for each identifier. List contains `NSString`s objects.

```
NSArray *centralManagerIdentifiers = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey];

for (NSString *centralManagerIdentifier in centralManagerIdentifiers) {
    CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                                            queue:nil
                                                                          options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: centralManagerIdentifier}];

    [self.cenralManagers addObject:centralManager];
}
```

For more details please refer to [State Preservation and Restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1) in Core Bluetooth Programming Guide.

Comment: Thanks. I read the guide but I fail to understand when this method is called. I am unable to add a breakpoint to it and I am not sure how to test this.. thanks